# Ignoring a column when condition doesnt match in select query - SQL-Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

My requirement is to display a Column in select query when a condition satisfies and not to display the column when condition is not matched.

For eg : In this simple table below

Table: `XYZ`

```
Name    ID  Fairness
------  --  --------
harish  3   White
ravi    5   brown 
arun    2   black 
rahul   5   white
```

Query:

```
select name,
       case id when 5 then " I Like to learn more languages" end as Remarks,
       Fairness
from xyz
where id=2
```

My requirement is in the above query "Remarks" column should not be displayed in output, but my output is

Actual Output:

```
Name  Remarks  Fairness
----  -------  --------
arun  null     black
```

Expected Output:

```
Name  Fairness
----  --------
arun  black
```

i.e, I need remarks column to be displayed only if the id is 5 in where clause.

Please provide me help to ignore "Remarks" when the condition is not satisfied or met.

Comment: Under what condition do you want to call that query?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want the SQL [COALESCE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29#COALESCE) function?

```
select coalesce(myMaybeNullColumn, '') from foo
```

will give blanks instead of nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an else condition to your query to return blank for those cases you don't want to show.

```
select name,case id when 5 then " I Like to learn more languages" else "" end as Remarks, Fairness from xyz where id=2
```

Comment: he said "i.e, I need remarks column to be displayed only if the id is 5 in where clause" if he add "else "" " he would see the column which is empty

Comment: True, I misunderstood. but then without a stored procedure to achieve that in a select it is just impossible.
Maybe I would add the remarks to an existing column rather to create a new one (if that fulfill the requirements of course).

Comment: yeah full acc, on the other side i don't see his problem, because if call this select out of a prgrammcode, he could check the content of the second column there. and in pl/sql it is not really a problem